# FSA GOSSAMER ROAD CRANKSET with BB7800?

Tags: shimano, crankset

Can FSA GOSSAMER ROAD CRANKSET be used together with BB7800 Dura Ace from Shimano?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**No**. Although they appear to fit together, they're *slightly* different. I made this mistake once (except the other way round - shimano chainset in FSA BB) and knackered the BB very quickly. FSA BBs are pretty cheap and easy to get hold of though.

Comment: so FSA to FSA and shimano to shimano....they are not compatible ?

Comment: Afraid not ....